# Remote program execution from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I would like to delegate some parts of my program execution from my Raspberry Pi into a PC (such as request a routine in the pc and retrieve the result in the RasPi and use it). Is  there any hint I could use to search for? (Sockets, etc)

EDIT: Maybe I'm wrong with the explanation; I mean, articles about the state of art in this topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in many ways, the simplest would be, instead of routines, to simply make programs that take arguments and return a string representing the result and then use something like SSH, for example:

```
if RES=`ssh myPCaddress -l pi /home/pi/bin/liftLargeThings stuff`
  then
  echo "Executed successfully, result is $RES"
else
  echo "Failed.."
fi
```

However, the overhead is quite large, so this could be done only for quite intensive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used GNU parallel, with --sshlogin option, for this. No time now but I'll post an example when I have a chance. Same protocol as DusteD is suggesting.